# Student-Project allocation algorithms?

Tags: algorithm

Is anyone aware of any documented Student-Project allocation algorithms (similar to the Hospitals-Residents problem, which is a subset of a two-sided matching problem)?

*Update based on comment*

---

This is just for knowledge rather than implementation since I've already got an implementation for the allocation algorithm. Thanks.

Comment: Share the implementation if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't really give more details, we can only give you broad pointers.

First Check out: [Stable Marriage Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem).

And also search the web for [Bipartite matching](https://planetmath.org/BipartiteMatching) (or in cases of weighted edges: [Assignment Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), which can be solved using: [Hungaring Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm)).

Note that a solution to the stable marriage problem might also solve your problem, albeit with a fake project->student preference.

I expect one of the above (stable marriage/bipartite matching/assignment) will work for you, but can't really tell without more information.