# Is Recursion the Best Way to Solve My Candy Issues?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I've very new to programming and I've come up with a practice problem for myself that's proving very difficult for me. It's a lot of fun, but I could use some guidance! I don't have any actual code yet - I'm simply trying to think through it logically first.

**PROBLEM:**

**I have 10 types of candy:**

1. Snickers
2. Reese's
3. Hershey's
4. Candy Cane
5. Whopper's
6. Bubble Gum
7. Pay Day
8. Circus Peanuts
9. Cherry Sours
10. Hot Tamales

**I only have 2 of each candy, totaling 20 pieces (no more, no less).**

**I have 20 people - each of who has ranked their top 3 favorite candies from the list.**

*For example:*

*Sally's favorites in order:*

1. *Reese's*
2. *Circus Peanuts*
3. *Whopper's*

**GOAL:**

I want to distribute every piece of candy - each person getting exactly 1 piece of candy according to their list of top three favorites, but also considering every other person's top three list of favorites.

**EXCEPTION:**

It is possible of course that in the real world many people's lists could be similar which could result in an unideal distribution of candy. But for the sake of the exercise I'd like to assume that the list of rankings is random - meaning the chances of achieving a desired distribution of candy is very high - so I'd like not to worry too much about that edge case.

**SUDO CODE:**

```
personRankingList // List of people with their top 3 rankings

candyList // List of candy and number of pieces available

for person in personRankingList
    if rank1 is available in candyList
        assign rank1 to person
    else if rank2 is available in candyList
        assign rank2 to person
    else if rank3 not available in candyList
        assign rank3 to person
    else
        ??? I'm stuck ???
```

**THOUGHTS:**

I think this logic works fine up to a point, but I will inherently have to back track because I'm unable to look forward with this logic... only at what's in my lap at the time of the iteration. Eventually, I will reach a point that no rankings for the current person iteration are available, but not because they couldn't have been. Had say, Person 2, been given their number 3 ranking instead of their number 1 ranking, then it's quite possible, or even probable, that the current person iteration would be given a piece of candy that's in their top 3 rankings.

Obviously, this a compounding problem that gets more convoluted with the more candy options you give or the more people you have - at least with the logic I'm currently using.

**QUESTION:**

How can my logic be altered and/or what logic can I add to the equation that helps me "look forward" so to speak, so that I'm able to achieve the most optimized and even distribution of candy possible?

My instincts say that recursion could be used here, but I'm having trouble thinking through how that could work.

I appreciate any input/advice here!

I'm using Python 3, but haven't actually go into any code yet. I'm trying to work through my sudo code the best I can before I start trying to write the program.

Comment: OT: [sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) code is not [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode).

Comment: My intuition tells the first step might be to create a dictionary whose keys where candies and whose values were a list of people with that preference.

Comment: Hi. You problem is a simple version to a [fair item allocation problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_item_allocation). This problem and its variants have solutions that are linked in the wikipedia page and I suggest you go through them since the choice is dependent on the initial criteria you set.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allocation algorithm help, using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936675/allocation-algorithm-help-using-python)

Comment: Definitely this is one of those problems that feels simple at first blush, but when you get into it you realize that a fairly sophisticated algorithm is needed so that you can accomplish your competing goals of candy distribution and fairness to each individual.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind this could become a real time failure if not properly executed.

In reality, out of so many brands, people tend to like the most famous brand of candy.

Not just candy, In most of the products just one or two brands will have 70% of the market share and the rest 30% market share will be shared by the the rest of the brands.

The above statements have another hidden meaning. When just two brands take the 70% market share, It also means that 70% the users prefer that particular two brands. The rest of the customers prefer other brands. Also among the rest of the users, some of them may actually prefer that 2 brands but may not be buying due to some other reasons say affordability, family restrictions etc.,

When this is the thing, Let us imagine the least worst scenario. Out of 10 people, if seven had listed the same three most popular brands of candies, Then you'll fail from your commitment.

Because for fulfilling their needs, you totally need 7 candies from the three preferred brands. But you have only 6 candies. (3x2 = 6.)

To solve this, Either you should increase the available brands / reduce the number of persons / Or instead of giving 3 choice to each, you should increase the choice/ Or to have more candies in each brand.

But only the third and fourth option is practically possible. Because we won't be sure about the probability of people's preference in the first option. 2nd option -We can't reduce the people because that is the thing it is meant for. Also we should consider that the fourth option will increase the cost.

So, Number of choices to be given =
number of people / number of candies you have in each brand.

=10/2 = 5.

That is if you ask them to list their top 5 brands, you can satisfy everybody.

Candy brands I've assumed as A,B,C...J.
And person's name person1, person2, person3... person10
Here the solution is:

```
candy_brands = [chr(x) for x in range(65,75)]*2
dct ={}
people = ['person' + str(x) for x in range(1,11)]
preferences = [
                ('A','B','C','D','E'), 
                ('C','E','B','A','D'), 
                ('E','H', 'B','C','A'),
                ('B','C','D','A', 'H'),
                ('D','B','E','A','I'),
                ('H', 'B','D','C','F'),
                ('D','A','C','B', 'E'),
                ('E', 'B','C','I','D'),
                ('D','B','I','J','A'),
                ('C','A','B', 'E','D')]
for i in range(len(preferences)):
    
    x, j = preferences[i], 0
    while j<5:
        if x[j] in candy_brands:
            dct[people[i]] = x[j]
            idx = candy_brands.index(x[j])
            del candy_brands[idx]
            break
        j += 1

print(dct)


'''
Output:
{'person1': 'A', 'person2': 'C', 'person3': 'E', 'person4': 'B', 'person5': 'D', 'person6': 'H', 'person7': 'D', 'person8': 'E', 'person9': 'B', 'person10': 'C'}
'''
```